# GCC warning for unintended pointer arithmetic on string literals

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

With the constant chopping and changing back and forth between different languages, every now and then I find myself trying to write fragments of Python or JS syntax in C/C++.

One that's caught me out more than once is trying to append a number to a string literal with a `+` operator:

```cpp
foo(const char*);

foo("the number is " + 6);
```

Which happily compiles to pass a `char*` pointer to the string `"mber is "` into my function.  Even more fun, if I write:

```cpp
foo("the number is " + 20);
```

Is anyone aware of a warning option that can catch this?

Comment: If there were such an option I'd expect it to be enabled by default or enabled with `-Wall` or `-Weverything`. So if you're not getting a warning, I suspect the check doesn't exist.

Comment: However, I'm surprised the second snippet doesn't warn about the pointer out of range.

Comment: What about an argument of type `const std::string&`, at least in the C++ realm? C is going to *do what you ask* here, so if there's no warning that's sort of a you problem, as a lot of valid C code is not necessarily *intentional* C code. If this is a footgun sort of thing, that's going to be hard to "make safe". Maybe you could get in the habit of using templates strings in JavaScript and f-strings in Python as both of those are just junk as far as C and C++ are concerned, making the error immediate and obvious.

Comment: That will prevent using any string literal, they just want to catch the `+` error.

Comment: @user17732522 It may be legal, but it's not "intended". Warnings are often for things that are valid code but likely to be a mistake, like `if (foo = 1)`

Comment: @tadman Warnings are often for valid code.

Comment: BTW, that's not valid in Python, it will complain that you can't add a string and integer.

Comment: @Barmar For sure, but not in every case, as there are far too many of those to even begin to enumerate.

Comment: @OP: Can you please choose only C or C++. While a GCC warning would likely apply to both C and C++ mode, the suggested workarounds will be quite different between the two languages.

Comment: @Barmar Probably valid in JavaScript though.  Almost everything else is.

Comment: @user17732522 To be fair, he didn't ask for a workaround.

Comment: Voting to close because the c and C++ tags are raising conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC does warn about the out-of-bound pointer arithmetic as one would expect, via the `-Warray-bounds` warning that is included in `-Wall`. However optimizations need to be enabled for this to work, e.g. with the options `-Wall -O2` GCC 13 produces:

```
<source>:4:45: warning: array subscript 20 is outside array bounds of 'const char [15]' [-Warray-bounds=]
    4 |     some_function_that_takes_a_const_chr_ptr("the number is " + 20);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

For the in-bounds case Clang has a `-Wstring-plus-int` warning, but GCC currently does not have an equivalent.

A patch to implement an equivalent [was submitted in 2017](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2017-06/msg00729.html), but seems to have never proceeded further.

Answer (score 0):

Because macro replacement will not replace a macro found in its own replacement, you can interpose a macro in a function call. Consider this macro:

```
#define foo(argument)   foo(*&(argument))
```

If `argument` is the array of a string literal, we can take its address with `&`, and then the dereference with `*` produces the array, after which the usual array-to-pointer conversion occurs, and the function `foo` is called.

if `argument` is a string literal plus an integer, then array-to-pointer conversion occurs before `&` applies, so the operand of `&` is an rvalue, not an lvalue, and the compiler will complain.

Thus we have:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void foo(const char *x)
{
    printf("I am happy.\n");
}


#define foo(argument)   foo(*&(argument))


int main(void)
{
    foo("the number is ");      // This will compile without complaint.
    foo("the number is " + 6);  // This will get an error.
}
```

Comment: technically this does answer the question. But imho this creates more problems than it solves. Among other things now you can't define a method called `foo`.

Comment: Also, the `&` operator can be overloaded in C++, so you should use [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) instead, eg: `#define foo(argument) foo(*std::addressof(argument))`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The question is tagged C and C++.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Perhaps so, but that doesn't change what I said. If you needed to write such a macro and support both languages, you can use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to differentiate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I am not going to draft a C++ answer.